# How to add strict-transport-security header to a Grails Application

Tags: grails, hsts

I have a groovy code running on Grails server. How do i configure it for HSTS ? I looked through Groovy specs there is nothing i found useful.

This is what I want to achieve

When I look at any HTTP Response from the server. I must see a header such as below

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

Can you please suggest some pointers ?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to implement custom servlet filter, something like this:

```
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class HstsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public HstsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        response.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
    }
}
```

then you need to register it in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    hstsFilter(HstsFilter)
}
```

this code was tested on Grails 3.1.4

Comment: Used this code in Grails 5.2.5 in order to add security headers.
But we had to put the `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` at the very end of the `doFilterInternal` method, as otherwise the headers were not added.

Comment: can confirm that this works perfectly, thanks!